# What kind of visa do I need? (US)

Tags: usa, working-visas

I’m a mother with a dependent child in Canada. My daughter would love to go to a ballet school in Georgia and we have the means to go if I can find remote work there. I do plan to do work but my daughter is going there to study, do we need an M1 visa or something else, and how do we get it?

Comment: To make it clear, Georgia USA, not the country Georgia in Europe?

Comment: @Willeke the question is tagged "USA" and has "(US)" in the title, and as far as I can tell from the [original edit history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/157830/revisions) it was like that from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your daughter can get M1 to go to vocational school in the US. For you, you might be able to go on B2 visitor status to accompany her, but you cannot work on B2.